# Read More Function for unordered list using jQuery with Paragraph

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, wordpress

I'm a beginner, and trying to understand everything. I tried using `<p>` and it works smoothly but when I insert a text like a `ul` and `li` it wont show up

I also tried using a `div` but only the `<a>` part is working not the `ul` and `li`. I hope someone can help me.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".more-less").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().prev('ul.more').toggleClass("main");
    if ($(this).parent().prev('ul.more').hasClass('main')) {
      $(this).text('Read Less');
    } else {
      $(this).text('Read More');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.more {
  text-align: left !important;
  display: none;
}

.more-less {
  /* position: absolute; */
  /* right: -30px; */
  /* top: -34px; */
  color: #e43330 !important;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="text-align: left;">First paragraph then cuts...
  <p class="more">Second paragraph.</p>
  <p><strong>Header key roles</strong></p>
  <ul class="more">
    <li>trait 1</li>
    <li>trait 2</li>
    <li>trait 3</li>
    <li>trait 4</li>
    <li>trait 5</li>
  </ul>
  <a class="more-less">Read More</a> &nbsp;
  <p> end paragraph</p>
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 1):

There's two main issues in your code. Firstly the `ul.more` is not a parent element of the clicked `p`, so `parents().next()` isn't the correct traversal logic to use. As the target element is a sibling of the one which raised the event, use `siblings()`.

Secondly, you need to set `display: block` on the hidden `ul`. You can do this through CSS, on the `.main` class which you toggle.

Also note that you cannot nest `p` elements. I corrected this in the example below by converting the containing element to a `div`.

```js
jQuery($ => {
  $(".more-less").click(function() {
    let $more = $(this).siblings('ul.more').toggleClass("main");
    
    if ($more.hasClass('main')) {
      $(this).text('Read Less');
    } else {
      $(this).text('Read More');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.more {
  text-align: left !important;
  display: none;
}

.more.main {
  display: block;
}

.more-less {
  color: #e43330 !important;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  First paragraph then cuts...
  <p class="more">Second paragraph.</p>
  <p><strong>Header key roles</strong></p>
  <ul class="more">
    <li>trait 1</li>
    <li>trait 2</li>
    <li>trait 3</li>
    <li>trait 4</li>
    <li>trait 5</li>
  </ul>
  <a class="more-less">Read More</a> &nbsp;
  <p> end paragraph</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rory thank you for you feedback. Do you have idea in wordpress where you input a RAW Jscript so it will be applicable to that specific page only. I tried the said code below but the problem is that it work. But in code playground it does. Is there anything I missed or I need to consider copy pasting  the code you provided? 
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".more-less").click(function() {
let $more = $(this).siblings('ul.more').toggleClass("main");
if ($more.hasClass('main')) {
$(this).text('Read Less');
} else {
$(this).text('Read More');
}
});
});
</script>
I had it like this

Answer (score 0):

Try delete `display: none;` from `more class`

Comment: You should copy the snippet down here and demonstrate your solution.